# What does the operators like I# and +# mean in GHC.Num module?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I opened up `GHC/Num.lhs` file and could find some codes like following:

```
instance  Num Int  where
    I# x + I# y = I# (x +# y)
    I# x - I# y = I# (x -# y)
    negate (I# x) = I# (negateInt# x)
    I# x * I# y = I# (x *# y)
    abs n  = if n `geInt` 0 then n else negate n

    signum n | n `ltInt` 0 = negate 1
             | n `eqInt` 0 = 0
             | otherwise   = 1

    {-# INLINE fromInteger #-}   -- Just to be sure!
    fromInteger i = I# (integerToInt i)
```

Are they some kind of intrinsic operators for GHC implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are [GHC primops](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/PrimOps), i.e. primitive operations that are not implemented in Haskell, but provided by the runtime.

These particular ones are [declared in `GHC.Prim`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.4.0.0/docs/GHC-Prim.html) and implement [unboxed `Int`s](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.4.0.0/docs/GHC-Prim.html#g:3): `Int#` is the type of unboxed `Int`s, `I#` is the constructor of `Int` (i.e. `data Int = I# Int#`), and `+#` is `Int#` addition.